# unique index in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, unique, unique-index

I have a PostgreSQL table with **unique index**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.batterysensorhistory_id_seq NO MINVALUE NO 
MAXVALUE NO CYCLE;
CREATE TABLE batterysensorhistory
(
    id integer DEFAULT 
nextval('batterysensorhistory_id_seq'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
batteryid uuid NOT NULL,
sensorid integer NOT NULL,
isactivelink boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
...
);

create unique index on batterysensorhistory (batteryid, sensorid, isactivelink)
where isactivelink = TRUE;
```

I want to set a constraint that only one row with same batteryid && sensorid can have *isactivelink = true*, but my **unique index** don't work.

Also, I create this example in sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c3b37/1

Any idea, whats wrong, with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
create unique index on batterysensorhistory (batteryid, sensorid)
    where isactivelink = TRUE;
```

But your version should work.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/908c8/2) is an example of it failing.